# Inequality for an $n$ sided convex polygon

Tags: geometry

If $a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots,a_n$ are the $n$ sides of a convex polygon, then prove that:
$${a_1\over p-a_1}+{a_2\over p-a_2}+\dots+{a_n\over p-a_n}<2,$$
where $p$ is the perimeter of the polygon.

I'm stuck. Don't know how to begin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See, any side of a polygon can't be longer than the other sides combined: $a_1<a_2+\dots+a_n$. Therefore $2a_1<a_1+\dots+a_n=p$. In other words, $a_1<{p\over2}$, which means $p-a_1>{p\over2}$. The same applies to any other side, not just $a_1$.

Now if you change all denominators to the smaller value $p\over2$, you'll get:
$${a_1\over p-a_1}+{a_2\over p-a_2}+\dots+{a_n\over p-a_n}<{a_1\over p/2}+{a_2\over p/2}+\dots+{a_n\over p/2}={a_1+\dots+a_n\over p/2}={p\over p/2}=2$$